# Colorpicker throws error "k(...).colpick is not a function" after javascript minification

Tags: javascript, color-picker

Hello I am facing a wierd issue that colorpicker doesnt work after the javascript file is minified and $ is assigned a variable named 'k'. It works when i try with $. My code:

```
requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            jquery: "/js/jquery/jquery",
            "datatables.net": "/js/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
            "datatables.net-css": "/js/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.min",
            tippy: "/js/tippy.all.min",
            fixedHeader: "/js/datatables/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min",
            "fixedHeader-css": "/js/datatables/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min",
            jquerymin: "/js/jquery-1.10.2.min",
            colpick: "/js/colpick",
            colpickcss: "/css/colpick"
        },
        shim: {
            "datatables.net": ["jquery", "css!datatables.net-css"],
            fixedHeader: ["css!fixedHeader-css"],
            colpick: ["css!colpickcss"]
        }
    });
    require.config({
        priority: ["jquery", "jquerymin", "colpick"]
    });
    require(["jquery", "tippy", "datatables.net", "fixedHeader", "jquerymin", "colpick"], function (k, s)



k(".colpick").css("display", "block");
                var t;
                k("#displayarea").colpick({
                    layout: "hex",
                    submit: 0,
                    submitText: "OK",
                    colorScheme: "dark",
                    onSubmit: function (u, x, v, w) {
                        k(w).val(x);
                        t = "#" + x; 
                        k(w).colpickHide();
                        p.createChart()
                    }
                }).keyup(function () {
                    k(this).colpickSetColor(this.value)
                })
```

Is there a way to solve this issue. Rename happens during minification but how can i prefer '$' sign instead of the variable 'k'. Thanks.

Comment: What are you using for minification?

Comment: @JeremyHarris minify-maven-plugin:1.7.6

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed. Seems like it was due to reference to jquermin, when i removed from require function it works as expected.